# How can we differ LEFT OUTER JOIN vs Left Join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, outer-join

What is the difference between `Left Join and Left Outer Join`?

Comment: Well not an exact duplicate because that was for SQL Server, but it's basically the same answer.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: enable Javascript in your browser, while you are typing the question, you could see other questions same as yours

Comment: @Hao LOL u r browser Hacker!!! and my mind hacker as well how did u come to know that ??
:)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

They are the same thing in MySQL. A `LEFT JOIN` is a synonym or shorthand for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 19):

There is none. The keyword OUTER is optional. They mean the same.