# SQL Insert if NULL

Tags: mysql

Is there a purely SQL way to do this?

I have a table `apples`: `id, price`, and another `apple_info`: `apple_id, color`

For each row in `apples`, I want to add a corresponding row in `apple_info`, if it does not already exist. Can't find any examples of this.

Comment: as each apple is inserted, or after the fact against the whole apple table? How is color value provided for the insert into apple_info?

Comment: after the fact (it will be some set value that I choose)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
insert into apple_info (apple_id, color)
select a.id, 'some_color'
  from apples a
  left outer join apple_info ai
    on (a.id = ai.apple_id)
 where ai.apple_id is null;
```

You will insert a row on `apple_info` with non existent `apple_id` and a fixed value for `color`. I guess this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I had in mind. `LEFT OUTER JOIN` threw me off, but turns out it's the same as `LEFT JOIN` in MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809594/basic-question-left-outer-join-vs-left-join

Answer (score 1):

Use [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO apple_info(apple_id, color)
    SELECT id, 'green' FROM apples
```