# SQL join and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have these tables

```
products
-------------
id | title  | 
-------------
1    Cheese  
2    Milk
3    Water
```

etc .....

```
products_to_city

    -----------------------
    city_id | product_id   | 
    -----------------------
    1         1
    1         2
    2         3
    3         1
    3         1
```

I am using this sql query to fetch the result

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 p.title
 FROM products p
 LEFT JOIN products_to_city ptc ON ptc.id = 1
```

The problem is that the query above fetches all data from table instead of only where city is 1

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: what you want to say by 1 in your query? the id or the field number?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't tell the query what to join `products` and `products_to_city` on.  Especially with the `LEFT JOIN` which will force a result set to include every record in `products` for every record in `products_to_city`.  I think you want this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_to_city ptc
  ON p.id = ptc.product_id
WHERE
  ptc.city_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 p.title
 FROM products p
 INNER JOIN products_to_city ptc ON ptc.id = p.id
 where ptc.id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You aren't joining products to city, you are getting a match of all the products and city.

```
SELECT
 p.id,
 p.title
 FROM products p
 LEFT JOIN products_to_city ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.id
 where ptc.city_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an outer join, so where no match is made, you get the row returned anyway. Consider an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
LEFT JOIN products_to_city ptc
```

you're telling MySQL (all SQL dbms, actually) to return all the rows from products, even if they don't match the join condition.

To return only those rows that match the join condition, use

```
INNER JOIN products_to_city ptc ON ptc.product_id = p.id AND (something else)
```

Note that you need to join the tables using the right column names.

I'm not sure what you want in that "something else" clause, because something like you wrote--pct.id = 1--is normally something you might express in a WHERE clause. The problem is that the products_to_city table doesn't have any column named "id".

Answer (score 0):

Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`

That's because `LEFT JOIN` took even the rows (at the left of the join) that haven't a corrisponing key into the right table.

The `JOIN` tooks only the colum from "left" and "right" tables that satisfies the *pk* and *fk* match

So this will be your solution

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.title
FROM products p
JOIN products_to_city ptc ON ptc.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

see Basic Question : LEFT OUTER JOIN vs Left Join, (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809594/basic-question-left-outer-join-vs-left-join)
they are the same. 
you want left inner join.

Answer (score 0):

```
LEFT JOIN products_to_city ptc ON p.id = ptc.id
```

Comment: missed where ptc.id = 1 like in other anwers