# Reverse effect of JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I got two tables :

- A list of people;
- A list of people I want to ignore.

When I read the list of people, I don't want to see the ignored people in the list.

My current solution is to query a second time the database (to select the people I want to ignore) and remove them from the array I create with PHP. It's working and it's fine.

However, I want to do that in MySQL. I know `JOIN` will join only if the row exists in the other table. I am looking for something different (won't show the entry IF the row exists).

I have searched in Google but the lack of "keywords" for this gave me no results.

Thanks

Comment: which is your database structure? we can't help you without any source code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Person
LEFT OUTER JOIN IgnoredPerson
ON Person.id = IgnoredPerson.id
WHERE IgnoredPerson.id IS null
```

---

Explanation:

[image]

> Exclude the records we don't want from the right side via a where clause

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Is the `OUTER` part needed?  Isn't this just a `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat [`LEFT OUTER JOIN === LEFT JOIN`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809594/basic-question-left-outer-join-vs-left-join), but I like being explicit.

Comment: @MattBall: Thanks, I've just always learned it as `LEFT JOIN` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your schema, I'd suggest something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT person_id FROM ignored_people)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM people p WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT i.id FROM ignorePeople i where p.id = i.id )
```

[here's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) a link about EXISTS in MySql