# SQL join 3 tables with empty record when no info

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having difficulty to understand what I would like to achieve :S - sorry about my English

I have a product table with a location history ID
I have a history table with a location ID and last transferred date
I have a location table with the location names

Tables:

```
**site_product**
product_id
product_name

**site_trans**
trans_id
trans_product - link the product
trans_inventory - for the location
trans_date2 - date when it was assigned

**site_location**
location_id
location_name
```

I use PHP to build an table to gather all the info together it is working and I have all columns sorted a part of the location.

Here is my working version BUT without the location names... (if that helps)

> SELECT *  FROM site_trans WHERE trans_product=product_id (e.g. 659) ORDER BY
>   trans_date2 DESC Limit 1

It gives the location ID number but I would like to go further and get the location name see above. If there is one it does nothing so leaves.

Question:

how to link the location to this to make it work? Please.

Could someone to light the way how I could do a Select if within please?

(I am a beginner in many ways so even a lecture would be appreciated to start with)

UPDATE1:
 LIMIT 1 is designed for the last location

Comment: how about a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: @Latheesan Kanes isn't `left join` exactly the same as  `left outer join` in mysql? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2809609/520857

Comment: first of all you should remove LIMIT 1 to get more results

Comment: Hi thanks for that unfortunately didn't work I only get one record

Comment: Which table does transdate2 belong to?

Comment: site_trans do I need to add that as well to the sql?

Comment: post your tables structure. you don't use any alias in there idk how your query works it should say that on clause is ambiguous...

Comment: A [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your schema and a few rows will help a lot.

Comment: @Marius.C I have added the table strucure hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Brother, when you put "LIMIT 1" you're saying that you want just 1 record, so the sgbd will retrieve just 1 row.

You also should take a look at all kind of joins: http://www.devmedia.com.br/inner-cross-left-rigth-e-full-joins/21016

Maybe with the left join you can lose some data.

Comment: I have rephrased my question see if that make more sense. Thanks for your help.

Comment: SELECT trans.*, loc.* FROM site_trans as trans, site_location as loc WHERE loc.location_id = trans.trans_inventory; -- If I understood what you want, and this will work if the trans_inventory references location_id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.*, sl.location_name
FROM site_trans AS s
LEFT JOIN site_location AS sl ON sl.location_id = s.location_id
WHERE s.trans_product=646 
ORDER BY s.trans_date2 DESC 
Limit 1
```

I have had some help and here is the solution. Thanks for everyone. Amazing team